# cannot allocate vector of size n MB in R while executing through Java

Tags: java, r

I am facing an error while executing R code through java using Rengine. I don't know how to set max memory in java code using Rengine. Is there a way to set max memory for Rengine? May be like below

```
Rengine re = getREngine();
re.eval("options(java.parameters = '-Xmx10g')", false);
```

I know this is wrong syntax. Kindly guide me how to set this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this: http://www.bramschoenmakers.nl/en/node/726

```
> options( java.parameters = "-Xmx4g" )
> library( "rJava" )
```

but I think this options set max memory for java being executed from R. However, you would like to exceed R memory, where R is executed from Java so maybe you should extend R memory: `memory.limit(memory.limit()*2)`

Comment: Thanks for the update. My concern is, it works fine when the R code is running separately. but when we call the same R program through Java, it returns the error.

Comment: So probably in the `getREngine()` there might be a possibility to set R options such as R memory limit - I am not Java user but this sounds ok

Comment: Thanks Marcin.. I don't have such options in getREngine(). It simply returns the Rengine object. Let's see if someone replies here who knows R and Java connectivity.

Comment: Have you tried googling this out or checked similar question?

Comment: Checked but unable to find a proper solution.